# I am about to create a complex feature in a Ruby on Rails app, what's a good way to organize it out on paper before coding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails but have read a book and created small features before. I'm now about to create a big new feature for an application (it really just involves a lot of forms and relationships) and I was wondering if anyone has a good/consistent strategy for pre-coding.

Comment: Mine is not really an answer but more of an advice, it helps if you use tools like cucumber to get some business/logic writing before you code. Checkout some samples at http://cukes.info//

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it:

1. Divide the task into a bunch of small ones. (outline on a whiteboard/piece of paper)
2. Make each part work. (implementation)

   Keep in mind how other parts of the component will access it. (whiteboard)
3. Integrate. (whiteboard, implementation)

   Every time you do, *rewrite* both of the APIs improving things you didn't think about in part #2.
4. Make it all look nice. (whiteboard, implementation)
5. Think about speed. (whiteboard, implementation)

NB: *Do not break the order*

If you try to design everything on paper, and a simple whiteboard / a sheet of paper is not enough, then you might be over-engineering. Be careful with that.

If you follow this pattern, then you are very likely to avoid both over-engineering and bad design decisions.